# Foreach-loop in PHP doesn't "read" the table properly

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

The following code is supposed to create another html-option-field within the select-inpupt-field for each row that is found in the autoren_werke table.

But what happens is that the output is only one option field no matter how many entries the autoren_werke table contains.

I don't know why it wouldn't work with a foreach-loop but obviously it doesn't. What is wrong?

```
<?php  
$holeIdVonAutorenWerke = "SELECT * FROM autoren_werke";
$resultholeIdVonAutorenWerke = mysqli_query($db, $holeIdVonAutorenWerke);

foreach($resultholeIdVonAutorenWerke as $row) {
$autor_id = $row['autor_id'];
$werk_id = $row['autor_id'];

$holeAutorenInfos = "SELECT vornamen, nachname, weitere FROM autoren WHERE id = $autor_id";
$holeAutorInfosResult = mysqli_query($db, $holeAutorenInfos);
$autorenInfos = mysqli_fetch_row($holeAutorInfosResult);

$holeWerkeInfos = "SELECT werk_titel FROM werke WHERE id = $werk_id";
$holeWerkInfosResult = mysqli_query($db, $holeWerkeInfos);
$werkInfos = mysqli_fetch_row($holeWerkInfosResult);


$option = "<option> $autorenInfos[0] $autorenInfos[1] $autorenInfos[2] $werkInfos[0]  </option>";
}

?>    

<select>
<?php echo $option ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You assign `$option` every loop and overwrite what was there. You probably want `$option .= ...` so it will add to it.

Comment: You need to use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php or any similar `fetch_*` method.

Comment: Running queries in a lopp driven by a query is an anti-pattern. Use a join in a single query.

Comment: @symcbean can you tell me what to google for so that I can find more information? I don't get what you mean, but it sounds important.

Comment: try "SQL JOIN" - you should be using `SELECT * 
FROM autoren_werke aw
JOIN autoren ar ON ar.id=aw.autor_id
JOIN werke wr ON wr.id=aw.werke_id`

(and using positional arguments in the return value - i.e. mysqli_fetch_row rather than mysqli_fetch_array - particularly along with "select *" is another bad practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the records/rows one at a time. Then concatenate the data into $option

```
// set option to a blank string
$option = '';
// using fetch array to get rows from the DB one at a time
while($row = fetch_array(resultholeIdVonAutorenWerke)){

    // note the .= to concatenate the option data
    $option .= "<option> $autorenInfos[0] $autorenInfos[1] $autorenInfos[2] $werkInfos[0]  </option>";

}
```